# Split column into deciles with equal rows. How to enforce ignoring repeated values

Tags: pandas, split

Below is example data which are probabilities from predict_proba. I want to split this data frame into deciles but with equal number of rows in each decile. I used pd.qcut but with that because of the repeating values at the boundary the rows in each decile become unequal.
[image]

I used below method to get equal splits which worked but problem is with this approach I can't get bins(range).

test_df["TOP_DECILE"] = pd.qcut(test_df["VALIDATION_PROB_1"].rank(method='first'), 10, retbins = False, labels = [ 10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100])

For each decile we need to see the probability range as well. This is how we need final output:

[image]
Is there a clean implementation we can do achieve this?

Comment: can you explain what is the desired result?

Comment: @David See the table (scshot) I have added at the bottom of description. This output is by using pd.qcut. TOP_DECILE & PROBABILITY_RANGE are two columns that we need to add. Problem with this output using pd.qcut is that it is splitting decile unevenly because of repeated values at boundary. We want equal cut that is business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented finally:

test_df["TOP_DECILE"] = pd.qcut(test_df["VALIDATION_PROB_1"].rank(method='first'), 10, retbins = False, labels = [100,  90,  80,  70,  60,  50,  40,  30,  20,  10])

test_df = test_df.merge(test_df.groupby('TOP_DECILE')["VALIDATION_PROB_1"].agg(['min', 'max']), right_index=True, left_on='TOP_DECILE')

test_df["PROBILITY_RANGE"] = "[" + (test_df["min"]).astype(str) + " - " + test_df["max"].astype(str) + "]"

But there should be a cleaner approach.